# Database insert issue

Tags: .net, frameworks, insert, entity

I have this bug in my application which I have no idea how to fix.

I have 5 tables:

```
Customer
Branch
PointOfSale
User 
CustomerEndUser
```

which have the following relationships :

```
Customer->Branch one-to-many 
Branch->PointOfSale one-to-many 
Customer->CustomerEndUser one-to-many 
User->CustomerEndUser one-to-one 
PointOfSale->CustomerEndUser one-to-many
```

I am using ADO.NET Entity Framework to accomplish database transactions.

When I want to add a new CustomerEndUser, I have to give it a PointOfSale, a User and a Customer. But Everytime I call the Insert method for the CustomerEndUser, the method throws an exception : "Entities in 'idenTTsystemEntities.PointOfSaleSet' participate in the 'FK_PointsOfSale_Branches' relationship. 0 related 'Branches' were found. 1 'Branches' is expected.The site administrator will be notified. Please try again later.", even though I give the CustomerEndUser the required information.

Here is the code I use in my Insert method :

```
public static CustomerEndUser InsertIntUser(CustomerEndUser endUser)
    {
        idenTTsystemEntities context = new idenTTsystemEntities();
        var mbr = Membership.Providers[INTMembershipProviderName];
        MembershipCreateStatus userStatus;

        if(mbr==null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException("Membership Provider is null");
        }

        MembershipUser mbrUser = mbr.CreateUser(endUser.Username, endUser.Password, endUser.Email, "no question",
                                                "no answer", true, Guid.NewGuid(),
                                                out userStatus);

        if(userStatus==MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
        {
            ProfileBase profileBase = ProfileBase.Create(endUser.Username);
            SettingsPropertyValueCollection profileProperties =
                profileBase.Providers[INTProfileProviderName].GetPropertyValues(profileBase.Context,
                                                                                   ProfileBase.Properties);

            //add the firstname, lastname and dateofbirth properties
            profileProperties["FirstName"].PropertyValue = endUser.FirstName;
            profileProperties["LastName"].PropertyValue = endUser.LastName;
            var shortDate = new System.Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo();
            shortDate.ShortDatePattern = "dd.MM.yyyy";
            profileProperties["DateOfBirth"].PropertyValue = Convert.ToDateTime(endUser.BirthDate, shortDate);

            //get the id of the newly created end user
            Guid newUserId = (Guid)mbrUser.ProviderUserKey;

            //add the user to the CustomerEndUser
            User newUser = context.UserSet.Where(u => u.UserId == newUserId).First();
            endUser.User = newUser;

            //get the customer to which the end user belongs to
            Customer cust = context.CustomerSet.Where(c => c.CustomerId == CustomerId).First();
            endUser.Customer = cust;

            //get the pos selected in the insertform
            Guid posId = endUser.PosId;
            PointOfSale selectedPos = context.PointOfSaleSet.Include("Branch").Where(br => br.PointOfSaleId == posId).First();
            endUser.PointOfSale = selectedPos;

            endUser.EndUserId = Guid.NewGuid();

            context.AddToCustomerEndUsers(endUser);

            profileProperties["Language"].PropertyValue = "de-DE";
            profileBase.Providers[INTProfileProviderName].SetPropertyValues(profileBase.Context, profileProperties);
            profileBase.Save();

            context.SaveChanges();

            return endUser;
        }

        throw new MembershipCreateUserException(userStatus);
    }
```

Google says this can be fixed by using a stored procedure, but I'd like a different solution if possible. Thank you!

Cheers, 
Alex Barac

Answer (score 0):

U should notice that the `PointsOfSale` should be related to at least 1 `Branch`. 
Same for the `Customer`, it should also be related to a `Branch`.

So the solution is when u load the PointsOfSale, u should also load his related Branch.(Same for Customer).
U know how to do this, right?

Comment: '.Include("Branch")' in the 'selectedPos' definition does just that. When I check the contents of the 'selectedPos', it does have a Branch inside it, but the same exception gets thrown. I'm not sure the exception is related to the Customer or not.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved, and it wasn't related to the insert method. Everytime I wanted to create a new EndUser, inside its constructor I also created a new PointOfSale and attached it to the EndUser, so the EntityFramework considered I was inserting a PointOfSale as well, and expected a Branch, even though I did supply one. Instead of creating a new Object inside the constructor, use its Reference.IsLoaded and Reference.EntityKey properties created by the EntityFramework.

I hope this makes enough sense for those who have similar issues.

Thanks,

Alex Barac